# Dismissing modal view hiding view controller behind status bar

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller

I am facing strange issue, when I am presenting any modal view say, someModalViewController on mainViewCntroller my mainViewController's 20px height is hiding behind status bar when I dismiss modal view.This problem does not occur if I rotate the simulator, but if I do not rotate simulator this problem is happening.Once I rotate simulator no matter how many times I launch modal view and dismiss it, mainViewController is appearing properly.
To check where the actual problem is first I created maninViewController without supporting orientation.That time it was working fine but when I returned TRUE in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation the same problem occurred again.

Can anyone know why this problem is coming and how to resolve that?

Comment: Hey Nuzhat, did you figure it out ?

Comment: i am also facing same issue. let me know if you found any solution for this.